# Given that, according to Kant we can only know appearances, how can he claim that space and time are not determinations of things in themselves?

Tags: kant

Given that Kant repeatedly stresses that we only have knowledge of appearances, and of their a priori conditions of possibility, with what right can Kant go on to assert that space and time can not be determinations of things in themselves? I accept Kant's argument that space and time are a priori forms of intuition, but surely this does not exclude the possibility of them ALSO being a determination of things in themselves? And surely, given Kant's insistence that we can have no knowledge of things in themselves, the strongest claim he could legitimately make would be one of agnosticism about whether things in themselves might be spatial and/or temporal?

Comment: It's an interesting question. I assume it's because Kant does make certain assumptions about things-in-themselves, among the assumptions is that their properties are completely disjoint from the properties of appearances. This does make sense. If the things in themselves had properties like appearances, then they would be appearances, wouldn't they?

Comment: What makes you think that he is *not* agnostic about any determination of things-in-themselves? I am pretty sure he is. What he does say, though, is that space and time *as we perceive it* most definitely is a characteristic of *our way of forming particular representations*, not things-in-themselves.

Comment: Surely this "possibility" is excluded because it is nonsensical. What does it even mean that things beyond any possible experience are "determined" by forms of experience? It is like something defined as untouchable being, nonetheless, soft to touch. Space and time (for Kant, anyway) lack purely intellectual conceptions that would allow even their formal application to things in themselves. They are mutts of intellect and sensibility.